# Programmatically loading a new process in a new GNU screen window

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

How do I load a new process to a new window of an existing session. I know that this can be done using keyboard shortcuts, but that is not what I'm looking for. I want to use this in conjunction with the python module fabric and open 8-9 different processes simultaneously and hence I am looking for the bash command(s) to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
screen [options] command
```

If you give the `screen` command a command as an argument, and the environment variable `$STY` is set, it will launch the command in a new window in the current sesion.